# How to implement auto log out in spring security and configure it with front end technologies like Reactjs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am building a RESTful service where where the user registers and login's in to the account and all the REST endpoint after logging in require a JWT bearer token to be authenticated, so basically I would have a access token and refresh token that would help me maintain the session. I have a backend written in Java where I have a MySQL database that holds the access token of the logged in user. Now it works all fine, and when logging out it basically deletes the token from database and redirects to the login page.
Now if I have to logout when the user is inactive for a period of time how do I do this? I would have to delete the token in the database as well and if the token expires I could not even do that which is a major bug in the project. Are there any solutions to this problem?

note: This is written in Java version 17 without XML configuration. And only by using annotations.

I tried to set a timer in the react app and hit the logout api when the timer ticks. But how do I do this in a different approach is there a way to do this in backend service and let the front end redirect to logout after deleting the token from database?

Comment: Your backend is stateless; it has no concept of a session. Your front end maintains your session; that's where you'll want to set the timeout.

Comment: you should never hand out JWTs to browsers, but if you have a cookie. If the user has timed out, all you do is that when the user does a request you check the session in the database and in that database you should also store the validity time. If that time has passed you delete the session.